# Select Data from Table and Insert into a different DB

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using python and psycopg2 to remotely query some psql databases, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to select the data I need from the remote table, and insert it into a table on a separate DB (local application server).

Most of the stuff I've read has directed me to avoid executemany and look toward COPY operations, but I'm unsure how to implement this on a specific select statement as opposed to the entire table. Should I be headed this way or am I completely off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I'm unsure how to implement this on a specific select statement as opposed to the entire table

COPY isn't limited to tables, you can use a query as the source as well, check out the examples in the manual, it shows how to use COPY to create a text file based on a query:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html#AEN59055
(3rd example)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://ryrobes.com/featured-articles/using-a-simple-python-script-for-end-to-end-data-transformation-and-etl-part-1/

Granted, this is pulling from Oracle and inserting into SQL Server, but the concepts should be the same.

Comment: This basically just says copy the query results to a list, prepare your insert statement, and pipe that list to executemany. How does this perform with larger datasets vs other solutions like COPY operations?